# Selenium code to Press F12 and navigate to source tab

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, robot

Can please anyone guide me how i could Press `F12` and than navigate to source tab in Developer tool in Chrome.

I was able to do it till pressing `F12`, but i am not able to Navigate to source, since the focus is not moved to developer tool so that with Tab click we could navigate to source tab.

**Code for Pressing F12-**

```
robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
```

Could anyone please suggest me some solution or work around.

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: No how; Selenium is an API for communicating with browsers through the webdriver protocol, and that's it. The DevTools is a desktop's app component, in no way exposed for interaction through webdriver. And what you've done with the Robot framework is to simulate physical interaction with the desktop app; your only option is to continue in that direction, but not to call it - or try to get it done with - Selenium.

Comment: actually my goal is to, open an application URL that i want to automate, and open developer tool, navigate to source tab and set broke point and reload the url. This is the complete flow that i want to automate. Could you suggest how i can achieve?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636877/631619

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to get the html source code, you can do that using

```
driver.getPageSource()
```

You generally can't access stuff like that, the way you are trying to, because selenium is sandboxed  your browser.  You can access chrome dev tools using the dev tools API or a testing framework like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which has access to dev tools API.